# Is there a way in which I can automatically update a table in google slides linked to google sheets without clicking update?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm new to this so please bear with me! As the title states, I am trying to link a Google table to Google Sheets. I copy/pasted the table into Google Slides and linked it to the spreadsheet. Without having to click update, is there a way I can make it automatically update?

Sorry, I am completely foreign to code, so I have very little understanding of how this might work.

Anybody have any ideas on how to make this work? I would really appreciate it!

I have tried to use apps script but do not really know how to use it...

Comment: There is a 6-year-old feature request for being able to do this, but it hasn't been implemented yet: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64027131

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google slides auto update links /tables linked from google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897088/google-slides-auto-update-links-tables-linked-from-google-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not a way to do this automatically. So, to update the embedded Google Sheet in Google Slides, you would have to manually open the Google Slides presentation and then click on Update. I've tried looking for a Google Apps script to accomplish this, but have not been able to find anything thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information here on Stack Overflow.

[Google slides auto update links /tables linked from google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897088/google-slides-auto-update-links-tables-linked-from-google-sheet)

It appears that it is possible with a chart, but not a table.